How to customise the checkboxes of legends for a highcharts legends
We are trying to change the checkbox of the legends given by highcharts. But the checkbox are not taking any other properties other than the width and height that we given and background and placements are not getting changed.
const bitAreaChart = Highcharts.chart('bitkpicontainer', {
                        chart: {
                            height: '304',
                       
                            events: {
                              load(this: any) {
                                this.yAxis[0].setTitle({
                                    text: "Amount (" +currency + ')',
                                    style: {
                                      'font-family': "ProximaNova-Regular",
                                      'color': '#71808C',
                                      fontSize: '12px',
                                    }
                                })
                                this.xAxis[0].update({
                                  tickPositions: this.xAxis[0].tickPositions,
                                  labels: {
                                    formatter: function(this: any) {
                                      var temp = new Date(this.value)

                                      return monthNames[temp.getMonth()]+"'"+Highcharts.dateFormat('%y', this.value);
                                    }
                                  }
                                })
                                this.series.forEach((series: any) => {
                                  series.checkbox.checked = true;
                                  series.selected = true;
                                  })
                              }
                            },
                        },
                        colors: colors,
                        title: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        subtitle: {
                            text: ''
                        },
                        
                        xAxis: {
                            type: 'datetime',
                            dateTimeLabelFormats: { // don't display the dummy year
                                day: '%b-%y'
                            },
                            minorTickLength: 0,
                            tickLength: 0,
                            minPadding: 0,
                            maxPadding: 0,
                            style: {
                                textOverflow: 'none',
                                color: '#000000'
                            },
                            labels: {
                              y: 23,
                              style:{
                                fontSize: '12px',
                                'font-family': 'ProximaNova-Regular',
                                color: '#8C99A7',
                                'line-height': '13px',
                                textOverflow: 'none'
                              }
                            },
                        },
                         yAxis: {
                          min: 0,
                          labels: {
                            useHTML: true,
                            style:{
                              fontSize: '10px',
                              'font-family': 'ProximaNova-Regular',
                              color: '#71808C',
                              'line-height': '11px',
                              textOverflow: 'none',
                            }
                          },
                          title: {
                            text: "",
                          }
                        },
                        legend: {
                          useHTML: true,
                          itemMarginTop: 6,
                           itemDistance: 60,
                          itemCheckboxStyle: {
                            "width": "22px",
                            "height": "22px",
                            "background-color": "#50C9E3",
                          },
                          itemStyle: {
                            color: '#2C3241',
                            'font-family': 'ProximaNova-Semibold',
                            fontSize: '14px',
                            fontWeight: 'normal',
                            'line-height': '19px',
                            "textOverflow": 'none',
                            "margin-right": '50px',
                            "height": "17px"
                          },
                          labelFormatter: function(this: any){
                             return '<span>' + this.name +'helo <input type="checkbox" style="width: 20px; height: 20px; color: red; position: relative" />' + '</span>';
                           },
                          symbolWidth: 10,
                          symbolHeight: 10                              
                        },
                        tooltip: {
                            formatter: function(this: any) {
                                return this.series.name + " : " + Highcharts.numberFormat((this.y), 2, '.', ',');
                            }
                        },
                        exporting: {
                            buttons: {
                                contextButton: {
                                    enabled: false
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        plotOptions: {
                            series: {
                              showCheckbox: true,
                              dataLabels: {
   useHTML: true
 },
                                marker: {
                                    enabled: false,
                                    symbol: 'circle',
                                    radius: 2,
                                    states: {
                                        hover: {
                                            enabled: true
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                                events: {
                                  checkboxClick: function(this: any) {
                                    if (this.visible) {
                                      this.hide();
                                    } else {
                                      this.show();
                                    }
                                  },
                                  legendItemClick: function(this: any, e: any) {
                                    const chart = e.target.chart,
                                      index = e.target.index;
                                    chart.series[index].checkbox.checked = this.selected = !this.visible;
                                  }
                                }
                            }
                        },
                        series: [{
                          type: 'areaspline',
                            name: 'Behaviour Value',
                            data: bitData
                        }, {
                          type: 'areaspline',
                            name: 'Influence Value',
                            data: relationshipData
                        }, {
                          type: 'areaspline',
                            name: 'Transaction Value',
                            data: quantumData
                        }
                        // },{
                        //   type: 'line',
                        //   name: 'John',
                        //   data: quantumData
                        // }
                        ]

        }as any);

And the code added is not changing the checkboxes stylings and the positions
And it is looking like below image
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
But we want a customisation like below image :
[![enter image description here][2]][2]
What are the properties we can make here to change the checkboxes please help us here
[1]: https://i.sstatic.net/0paH1.png
[2]: https://i.sstatic.net/D1hPk.png

You can style the legend checkboxes in Highcharts using
itemCheckboxStyle option. And all the CSS options you can use you can find here: https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.CSSObject
